# How to display a component after condition angular

Tags: angular, typescript, boolean

I am trying to display a component from a template when a variable is true, like this:

```
<app-payment-intent *ngIf="paymentready" [data]="data"></app-payment-intent>
```

And this my component:

```
export class CarshopModalComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  componentParent: CarshopService;

  plan: any;
  company: any;
  packages: any;
  total: number;
  cspay: boolean;
  data: any;
  paymentready:boolean;  //The condition variable

  constructor(
    public auth: AuthService,
    private listUrl: UrListService,
    private router: Router,
    public bsModalRef: BsModalRef,
    public PaymentGatewaysService: PaymentGatewaysService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.actualiza();
    this.configurarPasarelas();
  }

  actualiza() {
    this.plan = this.componentParent.getplan();
    this.company = this.componentParent.getcompany();
    this.packages = this.componentParent.getpackages();
    this.total = this.componentParent.getTotal();
    this.cspay = this.componentParent.getcspay();
  }

  configurarPasarelas() {
...
    this.paymentready = true; //This is the condition to display the component from my template
  }
```

Even if the paymentready is in true, the template does not show the component...

As you can see, in the function `configurarPasarelas()` the variable is changed to true...

So, there is no reason of why this doesn´t display me the component..

Can you help me? Thanks!

Comment: Does the data is passed properly and is there in the app payment intent some conditions which is not showing the component

Comment: Well if i don´t put the condition, the component is displayed so i don't think that is the problem..

Comment: Are you sure the code goes up to the line ` this.paymentready = true;`  ?

Comment: Does the console log any error or something? Does the code reach the point `this.paymentready = true`?

Comment: Can you please share a minimal reproduction at stackblitz?